# E Flat Major - Guitar chords in roman numeral notation?

Tags: chord-progressions, chord-theory

Is there a way to write guitar chords, for example E7, in roman numeral chord numbers like I and II etc. ?? And if so, how?

Comment: Roman Numerals indicate scale degrees in a certain scale, not chords per se

Answer (score 3):

[Roman numeral analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis) is dependent to the [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(music)) you are writing in, while chords are absolute.
So, `E` may be `I` when writing in **E major**, but it may as well be `III maj` in **C major**. `E7` may be `I7` in **E major**, while it may be `III 7` in **C Major**.

So, relatively speaking, you can write chords in roman numberals, as long as you define the scale. The very common `C` - `Am` - `F` - `G` [chord progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_progression), could be interpreted to `I` - `VI` - `IV` - `V`, if you are writing (and obviously playing) in **C major**.

However, the same chord progression, could be `III` - `I` - `VI` - `VII`, if you are writing in `Am`, depending on the rest of the song (or this part of the song). Of course, assuming you are writing in the [natural A minor scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale#Natural_minor_scale)

Pardon my English, in case something is wrong.
I am not very familiar with these terms in English.

Comment: Sorry, I checked in the piano. Spoke too soon. That would be `V`,`I7`,`♭VII`,`I`. `D` is not natural in **E major**

Comment: Well, `F#m` is `II` and `C#m` is `VI`. See? It's not that hard.

Comment: I just saw in the title that you are writing in E **flat**. Do you mean `E♭` or `E`? Because if you are writing in `E♭` then, my answers are not accurate.

Comment: I am writing in E flat, I did mention this above if you scroll up in the comments. Don't worry about it though, thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, sorry, didn't see that. My inner musician (hidden deep inside, I am a programmer) just ignored that because I didn't want to hear an `E` inside an `E♭` song. Just kidding. Then, what you have, is probably a [modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_(music)) from `E♭` to `E major` in that part of your song.

Comment: @SarahLarry - if you're in Eb, would the chord sequence be A E7 D E?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But it is all key dependent. In E maj. E will be I, E7 = I7. Minors are usually represented with lower case, so Em7 = i7. Are you a little confused with minors and flats? You won't be the first! Love to know why it happens though.

As in the other answer, in A maj., E7 is shown as V7, whereas in B maj., E7 shows as IV7. So it will only work for a specific key, that root note/chord being I (or i if minor).

Answer (score 0):

In E flat (3 flats) the basic chords will be I Eb, ii Fm, iii Gm, IV Ab, V Bb, vi C, vii Ddim.   The same I, ii, iii ... sequence as in C major, but transposed.  Some of course can be 7s.  Use of the notes will focus attention on the fingering; use of the numerals highlights the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mavrosxristoforos. It sounds like a modulation within your piece. You can indicate that with square brackets for the duration of the modulation. So the E7 would be the V7 and A would be I, etc. If the E7 was by itself (meaning the other chords around it were all still obviously in Eb) then it could be that the E7 was some sort of Neapolitan chord. In this case it would actually be an Fb7 chord and you could write bII7 or NeoII7 or something to indicate that it was a different type of II chord.